# How can I get a Belkin N600 DB (F9L1101v1) to work on Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit

Tags: wireless

I could use some assistance to trying to get a Belkin N600 DB Wireless Dual-Band USB Adapter to work on a Dell Inspiron 1525 with 64-Bit Ubuntu 12.04. The device won't work out of the box. Tried to go the NDISWrapper route, but using the GUI, received the following message:

```
Module could not be loaded. Error was:
FATAL: Module ndiswrapper not found.
Is the ndiswrapper module installed?
```

Despite the fact that it showed up listed in the GUI, the device still did not function properly.

How should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

At this point, it looks like one solution is to build and install ndiswrapper from source.  I refer you to [Brian Zier's "Getting the Belkin N600 DB to work on Ubuntu" guide](http://www.brianzier.com/getting-the-belkin-n600-db-to-work-on-ubuntu):

> Uninstall the built-in ndiswrapper and clean up any configuration you
>   previously had:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ndiswrapper-common ndiswrapper-utils-1.9 ndisgtk
sudo rm /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/ubuntu/ndiswrapper/ndiswrapper.ko
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/ndiswrapper.conf
sudo rm -r /etc/ndiswrapper/*
```

> Next, build ndiswrapper from source:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ndiswrapper/stable/ndiswrapper-1.57.tar.gz
tar -xvf ndiswrapper-1.57.tar.gz
cd ndiswrapper-1.57
make
sudo make install
sudo depmod -a
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

This also works with `ndiswrapper-1.58`

*Disclaimer: While the excerpt above has gotten me past the issues with ndiswrapper itself, I haven't yet been able to complete the whole guide as to get the N600 working properly with my own WiFi, which I suspect may be due to my router's configuration. Your mileage may vary.*

Answer (score 0):

The Belkin F9L1101 is Based on the Realtek RTL8192 chipset, which has linux drivers available. So you can get this to install by downloading the RTL8192 driver source code and compiling.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192du.git
cd rtl8192du

make
sudo make install

modprobe 8192du
```

This worked perfectly for me. I'm connected to AskUbuntu right now with a F9L1101 adapter on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. I haven't tested this on any version less than 14.04, so I can't assure it will work, but worse case, if this fails on an earlier version of Ubuntu, you have the option of upgrading to 14.04.

If you can't plug in to get the internet connection you need to download this, just clone that git repository (first step) on a computer that does have internet and then use a flash drive to copy the drivers over to your computer. Then follow the remaining steps on your computer.