# Newbie to Ubuntu today w/Windows 7-64 bit dual boot system

Tags: wireless, networking, dual-boot

I just downloaded and installed Ubuntu on HD side-by-side W/windows7 64-bit, transitioning to Ubuntu & rid of windows eventually. I know zip about Ubuntu, but all seems fine except for my WiFi access. Currently using `Belkin wireless dual-band-600N` USB adapter in USB 3.0 port. Opened Terminal and did a `lsusb` it shows:

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 050d:110a Belkin Component
```

From there, I am totally lost....? Network Menu only shows LAN Ethernet Card which I'm not using... don't know how to config WiFi in Ubuntu.
James...

UPdate: I opened terminal, typed in  `uname -r` and the terminal replied with:

```
3.13.0-32-generic
```

It does not look right as installed Ubuntu-64 from ISO-DVD according to Instructions. My system is:

> 64-bit AMD APU-A8-3870 Quad-Processor, 8GB DDR3, Windows 7-64 bit

I have not been able to Update anything sine the Install as I have no Internet in Ubuntu, I only have Internet in Windows 7. I tried to install Wine...it wont install, and I tried to install `Cube64.zip` it wont install it hangs at Step #3 in tutorial.... It's been 3 days working on this w/out help, hopefully someone knows something...?

Comment: The exact solution depends on your kernel version. Please edit your question to add this information from the terminal: uname -r Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your wifi dongle is one of the few that requires some tinkering.

More exact, a ndiswrapper for your driver. I found another user, with out the same problem, and there was a guide for installing and setting up this ndiswrapper.

Check out the post here: [How can I get a Belkin N600 DB (F9L1101v1) to work on Ubuntu 12,04 64-Bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190791/how-can-i-get-a-belkin-n600-db-f9l1101v1-to-work-on-ubuntu-12-04-64-bit)

That guide is based on the information at this site: http://www.brianzier.com/getting-the-belkin-n600-db-to-work-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks Dan, that was yrs ago....I've just got hold of Ubuntu 18.04 yesterday...